# How to check if a user has discord nitro using a bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So pretty much as of now, my code checks if a user has nitro, on the user's avatar (like if it's a gif or not), although I want to make it so that it can also check without having to use the profile.

[image: A picture that I have nitro although my profile isn't a gif.]

[image: The bot saying I have no nitro]

Is there any way around this I could do?

Comment: It seems like bots cannot access the `premium` or `nitro` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [user profile](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Profile.premium) in *discord.py* to check if a user has nitro.
Example command:

```py
@commands.command(name="nitro")
async def has_nitro(self, ctx):
    user_to_check = ctx.author # you can specify any user (discord.User)
    user_profile = await user_to_check.profile() # get user's profile
    is_premium = user_profile.premium
    await ctx.send(is_premium) # for example send a result, you can use it as you like
```